# Mobiscroll auto theme usage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

How can I add auto theme selection to my mobiscroll datepicker?

The code i've now is not working:

```
    $("#datestartscroller").mobiscroll().date({
            theme: 'auto',
            display: 'modal',
            dateOrder: 'ddmmyy',
            mode: 'scroller',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the theme setting at all.
Just make sure you selected the auto theme plugin when downloading the package:

```
$("#datestartscroller").mobiscroll().date({
    display: 'modal',
    dateOrder: 'ddmmyy',
    mode: 'scroller',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
});
```

Comment: hmmm that doesn't work for me. I downloaded the package including the auto theme option and all themes. I removed the `theme: 'auto',` but am still left with the default theme.

Comment: When I use the theme-names specified however I the themes work correctly. But I want it to be automaticly set, so users on android see android style and users on iphone see ios style. Do you have any suggestions?